# Nonclustered indexes covering queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having an issue or two with the following;

> A nonclustered index can cover a query. Covering a query means that SQL Server can find
>   all data needed for the query in a nonclustered index and does not need to do any lookups in the base table.

Does this mean that the data is stored inside the clustered index leaf pages? I thought these contained pointers to the RIDs (heaps) and clustered index keys (clustered index) and the data was stored there?

Also the quote above mentions a 'base table' - is that the heap/clustered index? I'm learning to think of the word 'table' as being the form in which data is returned rather than the form in which it's stored, so to hear it referred to as a storage medium seems misleading.

Any advice/help appreciated.

Comment: The clustered index leaf pages **ARE** the data pages. When you have a clustered index, the table is a *clustered table* - no longer a *heap*, and thus no RID's are being used - the nonclustered index leaf pages will contain the **clustered index** keys as "pointers" back to the actual data page

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way to understand how this works would be an example.

Say you have a table `foo` with columns `a`, `b`, and `c`, and you run `CREATE INDEX foo_a_b ON foo (a, b)`.

The table might look like this:

```
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  1  |  1  |
|  4  | 10  | 42  |
|  2  |  4  | 42  |
|  5  | 16  |  1  |
|  3  |  8  |  1  |
```

If you now run the query `SELECT a, b, c FROM foo WHERE a < 5 AND b < 10`, the DBMS can use the index to find rows that meet the `WHERE` clause.

In order for that to be true, the index must have the values of `a` and `b` as accessible data. It might look something like this:

```
|  a  |  b  |  row_address  |
+-----+-----+---------------+
|  1  |  1  |     0xABDEFC  |
|  2  |  4  |     0xAFBDEC  |
|  3  |  8  |     0xFABDEC  |
|  4  | 10  |     0xCAFEBA  |
|  5  | 16  |     0xADDAFF  |
```

If we instead write `SELECT a, b FROM foo WHERE a < 5 AND b < 10`, something special happens: to select the values of `a` and `b`, we don't actually need to follow the pointer to the full row, we can just scan down the index outputting the pairs that match the condition:

```
|  a  |  b  |
+-----+-----+
|  1  |  1  |
|  2  |  4  |
|  3  |  8  |
```

This is true regardless of whether the pointer to a full row (which I've called `row_address`) points to an arbitrary heap address (in the case of a non-clustered table), or a location ordered based on some index key (in the case of a clustered table).

Comment: Thanks for your response. My understanding is that in a non clustered index, the leaf pages contain RIDs or clustered index keys. Is it the clustered index key that holds the data for both columns a and b (using your example above) so consequently if this is all the data that's required, it's sufficient for the non clustered index to retrieve it from the clustering key on it's leaf pages and consequently 'cover' the query off without needing to reference the base table?

Comment: @hwilson1 What you refer to as "RID" and "clustered index key" are both examples of the `row_address` field in my diagram - they're the *output* of the lookup on an index. Changing the table in my example to be clustered on `c` (a clustered index is not created beside the table, it is a way of storing the table) would change the `row_address` column. But the value of `row_index` makes no difference to my example, since all it relies on is the *input*, columns `a` and `b`, which have to be there for the index to function at all.

Comment: So irrespective of whether values in the row_address correspond to clustering keys or RIDs (do they correspond to them, or are they replaced by them?), so long as they're composed of columns a and b, there is no need to delve into the underlying table and the query is therefore 'covered' by the non clustered index?

Comment: @hwilson1 Take a look at the diagrams in the answer. You can find the result in the last diagram (the query result) based on the second diagram (the index), and don't have to care what is in `row_address`. You don't even need to know whether that `row_address` is a RID, a clustering key, or anything else, and you never have to look at the full table (the first diagram).

Comment: Ok that's clear now. Thanks very much for your answer.